Setting x and y limits for coord_polar in ggplot2 without clipping data
I've set up a specific and kind of unusual chart in ggplot using radial coordinates that has a consistent set of y-axis limits. I've recently run into a problem with data being clipped off from the outer portion of the chart that I'd like to avoid.
Here's the code for the plot
  pinwheel <- plot_sample_density %>%
    select(row_id, stroma_bins, contains("_cd8_frac")) %>%
    pivot_longer(contains("_cd8_frac"), names_to = "CD8 Location") %>%
    mutate(`CD8 Location` = sub("_cd8_frac", "", `CD8 Location`)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(row_id, value, fill = `CD8 Location`), width = 1) + # Ratio by bar breakdown
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = lower_lim, xmax = upper_lim, ymin = ymin_density, ymax = 0, fill = stroma_bins),
              data = stroma_comp, color = "black") + # Stroma bins
    scale_fill_manual(values=tissue_palette) +
    annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = -0.003540187,
             label = paste0(" "), size = 5,
             color = "black", hjust = 0.5) +
    xlim(min(stroma_comp$lower_lim), max(stroma_comp$upper_lim)) +
    ylim(-0.003540187, 0.005720250) +
    coord_polar(clip = "off") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.margin = margin(-5, -5, -5, -5)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

Here's what one of the plots looks like.

Here's the dataframe used to make it.
structure(list(Image = c("NG998 01 P1_Scan2.qptiff - resolution #1-EXTENSIVE TLS-COMPLETE-COMPLETE", 
"NG998 01 P1_Scan2.qptiff - resolution #1-EXTENSIVE TLS-COMPLETE-COMPLETE", 
"NG998 01 P1_Scan2.qptiff - resolution #1-EXTENSIVE TLS-COMPLETE-COMPLETE", 
"NG998 01 P1_Scan2.qptiff - resolution #1-EXTENSIVE TLS-COMPLETE-COMPLETE", 
"NG998 01 P1_Scan2.qptiff - resolution #1-EXTENSIVE TLS-COMPLETE-COMPLETE", 
"NG998 01 P1_Scan2.qptiff - resolution #1-EXTENSIVE TLS-COMPLETE-COMPLETE"
), Name = c("Tile 242", "Tile 71", "Tile 249", "Tile 277", "Tile 259", 
"Tile 239"), Object.ID = c("68a3aaf2-4194-49ff-a5bf-8f7be5bfe967", 
"927b0ec8-b13a-47ed-8f36-6c77b8260d08", "4e228ee3-c756-49ab-8d7b-50847846e072", 
"78c0e5fb-0a0c-4815-abb9-42cc1892b615", "5ebeb226-efb8-4337-96c2-63bb1a0157b4", 
"eb8975c0-f6a6-4cc4-bfea-0b1a4715fa7e"), Object.type = c("Annotation", 
"Annotation", "Annotation", "Annotation", "Annotation", "Annotation"
), Classification = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), Parent = c("Annotation (Positive*)", 
"Annotation (Positive*)", "Annotation (Positive*)", "Annotation (Positive*)", 
"Annotation (Positive*)", "Annotation (Positive*)"), ROI = c("Rectangle", 
"Geometry", "Rectangle", "Rectangle", "Rectangle", "Geometry"
), Centroid.X.µm = c(13927.3, 18928.2, 13427.2, 13927.3, 13927.3, 
12440.9), Centroid.Y.µm = c(14428.3, 9428.4, 14928.3, 16428.4, 
15428.4, 14440.1), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Mean = c(27.3768, 
22.1708, 27.4211, 22.8032, 24.8058, 28.5247), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Std.dev. = c(20.3606, 
18.8387, 20.0658, 16.6636, 18.2257, 22.039), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Min = c(3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Max = c(214L, 
200L, 231L, 186L, 195L, 191L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Median = c(23.5, 
15.5, 23.5, 18.5, 20.5, 23.5), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Mean = c(62.2827, 
68.229, 53.4022, 57.5713, 57.4357, 45.433), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Std.dev. = c(32.021, 
36.1589, 30.9971, 36.1066, 34.1193, 24.1057), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Min = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Max = c(196L, 
217L, 194L, 229L, 209L, 169L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Median = c(64.5, 
67.5, 54.5, 55.5, 58.5, 46.5), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Mean = c(22.2668, 
34.3178, 19.9982, 22.8416, 21.5093, 19.3385), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Std.dev. = c(12.0383, 
20.9852, 13.0198, 15.4806, 13.8251, 11.1417), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Min = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Max = c(96L, 
200L, 105L, 120L, 91L, 115L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Median = c(23.5, 
37.5, 21.5, 24.5, 23.5, 20.5), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Mean = c(19.9205, 
25.559, 24.4195, 27.9797, 24.9552, 21.2868), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Std.dev. = c(22.4406, 
22.6284, 24.9408, 26.9399, 24.6555, 18.307), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Min = c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Max = c(216L, 
173L, 236L, 183L, 221L, 201L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Median = c(12.5, 
15.5, 13.5, 14.5, 13.5, 14.5), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Mean = c(10.5174, 
8.957, 8.9497, 8.7182, 9.0166, 7.3118), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Std.dev. = c(6.33, 
6.1438, 9.6332, 6.5063, 7.3654, 6.0601), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Min = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Max = c(127L, 
43L, 215L, 40L, 195L, 189L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Median = c(10.5, 
9.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9.5, 7.5), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Mean = c(33.8812, 
30.1595, 30.7158, 31.9526, 30.5745, 28.1245), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Std.dev. = c(13.4767, 
16.2966, 14.2719, 16.9056, 15.7833, 12.5994), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Min = c(4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Max = c(157L, 
155L, 125L, 144L, 219L, 116L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Median = c(35.5, 
33.5, 33.5, 35.5, 33.5, 30.5), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Mean = c(6.1932, 
6.0509, 6.69, 6.9123, 6.47, 6.3333), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Std.dev. = c(3.1136, 
2.5192, 3.0181, 3.5535, 3.5341, 2.8685), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Min = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Max = c(104L, 
25L, 90L, 133L, 134L, 108L), ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Median = c(6.5, 
6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5), Num.Detections = c(2687L, 2142L, 2777L, 
2684L, 2601L, 2485L), Num.CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L), Num.COL1A1. = c(310L, 
217L, 675L, 677L, 523L, 349L), Num.COL1A1...CD8. = c(1L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Num.COL1A1...DDR1. = c(55L, 78L, 58L, 63L, 49L, 
25L), Num.COL1A1...DDR1...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK. = c(25L, 
70L, 24L, 51L, 28L, 6L), Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Num.COL1A1...PanCK. = c(1L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L), Num.COL1A1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Num.DDR1. = c(694L, 
21L, 708L, 240L, 492L, 980L), Num.DDR1...CD8. = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), Num.DDR1...PanCK. = c(1383L, 1690L, 1073L, 1476L, 
1375L, 803L), Num.DDR1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Num.PanCK. = c(1L, 14L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 32L), Num.PanCK...CD8. = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Area.µm.2 = c(250036.2, 249233.3, 250036.2, 
250036.2, 250036.2, 234249.7), Perimeter.µm = c(2000.1, 2311, 
2000.1, 2000.1, 2000.1, 1924.8), CD8.Total = c(2, 0, 2, 3, 5, 
5), COL1A1.Total = c(392, 379, 760, 797, 604, 383), DDR1.Total = c(2158, 
1859, 1863, 1830, 1946, 1814), PanCK.Total = c(1410, 1788, 1103, 
1542, 1406, 843), PanCK..DDR1..Total = c(155.8051, 321.803, 165.518, 
198.8222, 152.8344, 199.9802), PanCK..DDR1..Total.1 = c(1408, 
1760, 1097, 1527, 1404, 809), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Mean = c(21.8518, 
12.7061, 23.8603, 19.8247, 19.5981, 19.811), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Std.dev. = c(19.0394, 
14.6605, 21.5358, 17.5229, 18.766, 19.8776), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Min = c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Max = c(152L, 
200L, 182L, 157L, 195L, 191L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Median = c(14.5, 
7.5, 15.5, 13.5, 11.5, 10.5), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Mean = c(22.2444, 
27.849, 19.7637, 20.3125, 21.1161, 21.8021), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Std.dev. = c(16.4463, 
12.953, 14.6988, 12.7306, 16.1236, 15.0925), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Min = c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Max = c(139L, 
190L, 135L, 134L, 153L, 105L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Median = c(17.5, 
26.5, 15.5, 17.5, 16.5, 16.5), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Mean = c(7.2765, 
8.393, 6.4256, 6.9728, 6.9321, 10.5902), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Std.dev. = c(9.475, 
10.2543, 9.0327, 9.6804, 9.4016, 12.1883), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Min = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Max = c(89L, 
150L, 92L, 95L, 91L, 115L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Median = c(3.5, 
5.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 5.5), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Mean = c(58.8371, 
56.9002, 54.4831, 58.8556, 54.1173, 41.5618), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Std.dev. = c(32.6239, 
23.9819, 29.5833, 28.7155, 29.1736, 22.9962), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Min = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Max = c(216L, 
173L, 236L, 183L, 221L, 201L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Median = c(57.5, 
56.5, 52.5, 60.5, 54.5, 38.5), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Mean = c(2.8078, 
1.6683, 4.5885, 1.9958, 3.1894, 3.8371), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Std.dev. = c(3.8787, 
1.112, 15.9579, 1.9773, 8.2046, 8.8048), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Min = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Max = c(127L, 
16L, 215L, 40L, 195L, 189L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Median = c(2.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Mean = c(16.8942, 
9.0455, 16.0668, 13.4049, 13.7005, 16.3019), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Std.dev. = c(13.9118, 
10.1583, 13.4373, 11.8659, 12.8104, 12.1333), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Min = c(4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Max = c(157L, 
155L, 125L, 141L, 120L, 94L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Median = c(12.5, 
6.5, 11.5, 9.5, 8.5, 13.5), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Mean = c(10.1405, 
8.4058, 9.3212, 9.8351, 9.3041, 7.6135), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Std.dev. = c(4.7858, 
2.9356, 3.8909, 4.5507, 5.0072, 4.2971), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Min = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Max = c(104L, 
25L, 90L, 133L, 134L, 108L), Stroma.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Median = c(10.5, 
8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 9.5, 7.5), Stroma.Num.Detections = c(422L, 326L, 
954L, 879L, 690L, 607L), Stroma.Num.CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 4L), Stroma.Num.COL1A1. = c(304L, 215L, 672L, 660L, 516L, 
348L), Stroma.Num.COL1A1...CD8. = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    Stroma.Num.COL1A1...DDR1. = c(36L, 60L, 36L, 37L, 31L, 19L
    ), Stroma.Num.COL1A1...DDR1...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Stroma.Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK. = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 17L, 
    3L, 4L), Stroma.Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stroma.Num.COL1A1...PanCK. = c(1L, 11L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L), Stroma.Num.COL1A1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Stroma.Num.DDR1. = c(19L, 1L, 26L, 20L, 29L, 
    23L), Stroma.Num.DDR1...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
    Stroma.Num.DDR1...PanCK. = c(6L, 2L, 32L, 15L, 7L, 18L), 
    Stroma.Num.DDR1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Stroma.Num.PanCK. = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 24L), Stroma.Num.PanCK...CD8. = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Stroma.Area.µm.2 = c(37989.9, 55205, 67984.9, 
    75010.4, 68362.1, 67372.3), Stroma.CD8.Total = c(1, 0, 2, 
    3, 4, 5), Stroma.COL1A1.Total = c(346, 292, 716, 720, 553, 
    374), Stroma.DDR1.Total = c(65, 69, 99, 89, 71, 64), Stroma.PanCK.Total = c(12, 
    21, 43, 44, 12, 48), Stroma.PanCK..DDR1..Total = c(111.2515, 
    188.1473, 116.9583, 128.1532, 113.8337, 169.2785), Stroma.PanCK..DDR1..Total.1 = c(10, 
    8, 37, 32, 10, 22), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Mean = c(28.474, 
    24.9774, 28.7887, 24.0615, 26.8558, 32.0367), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Std.dev. = c(20.4288, 
    19.0127, 19.2458, 16.0538, 17.6, 21.8197), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Min = c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Max = c(214L, 
    200L, 231L, 186L, 164L, 186L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DAPI..Median = c(25.5, 
    20.5, 26.5, 21.5, 24.5, 29.5), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Mean = c(69.8267, 
    80.1547, 66.2334, 73.7494, 71.4364, 55.1259), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Std.dev. = c(28.4161, 
    31.8459, 25.472, 30.5972, 28.3968, 20.0974), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Min = c(3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Max = c(196L, 
    217L, 194L, 229L, 209L, 169L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..DDR1..Median = c(70.5, 
    80.5, 66.5, 72.5, 71.5, 55.5), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Mean = c(25.0682, 
    41.9256, 25.1226, 29.6703, 27.1241, 22.96), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Std.dev. = c(10.2313, 
    16.8227, 10.2158, 12.0172, 10.8298, 8.4264), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Min = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Max = c(96L, 
    200L, 105L, 120L, 89L, 72L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..PanCK..Median = c(25.5, 
    42.5, 25.5, 29.5, 27.5, 23.5), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Mean = c(12.835, 
    16.5583, 13.1197, 14.6488, 13.8668, 12.9891), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Std.dev. = c(8.7204, 
    11.3194, 7.84, 9.7302, 8.2606, 4.119), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Min = c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Max = c(153L, 
    142L, 157L, 150L, 130L, 111L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..COL1A1..Median = c(11.5, 
    14.5, 12.5, 13.5, 12.5, 13.5), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Mean = c(11.9696, 
    11.1026, 10.6292, 11.6348, 11.2652, 8.7404), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Std.dev. = c(5.6151, 
    5.3106, 4.7454, 5.5615, 5.5956, 3.6438), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Min = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Max = c(44L, 
    43L, 155L, 39L, 156L, 67L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD20..Median = c(12.5, 
    11.5, 10.5, 11.5, 11.5, 8.5), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Mean = c(37.0904, 
    36.3723, 36.2699, 39.9711, 37.0615, 32.9335), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Std.dev. = c(10.7237, 
    11.9897, 9.9987, 11.5886, 11.3958, 9.0903), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Min = c(4L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Max = c(99L, 
    105L, 121L, 144L, 219L, 116L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD45..Median = c(37.5, 
    37.5, 36.5, 40.5, 37.5, 33.5), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Mean = c(5.485, 
    5.3867, 5.7047, 5.6507, 5.4006, 5.8107), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Std.dev. = c(1.9838, 
    1.8867, 1.8037, 1.9612, 1.8659, 1.7674), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Min = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Max = c(47L, 
    22L, 20L, 32L, 66L, 17L), Tumor.ROI..2.00.µm.per.pixel..CD8..Median = c(5.5, 
    5.5, 6.5, 5.5, 5.5, 6.5), Tumor.Num.Detections = c(2253L, 
    1812L, 1803L, 1792L, 1906L, 1861L), Tumor.Num.CD8. = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1. = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 
    4L, 1L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...DDR1. = c(18L, 17L, 20L, 26L, 18L, 
    5L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...DDR1...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK. = c(20L, 63L, 19L, 
    31L, 25L, 2L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...DDR1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...PanCK. = c(0L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tumor.Num.COL1A1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Tumor.Num.DDR1. = c(674L, 20L, 681L, 220L, 463L, 
    956L), Tumor.Num.DDR1...CD8. = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Tumor.Num.DDR1...PanCK. = c(1373L, 1688L, 1035L, 1456L, 1367L, 
    781L), Tumor.Num.DDR1...PanCK...CD8. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Tumor.Num.PanCK. = c(0L, 11L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 6L), Tumor.Num.PanCK...CD8. = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tumor.Area.µm.2 = c(210182, 193063.2, 180106.4, 
    174159.8, 180780.5, 165747.1), Tumor.CD8.Total = c(1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0), Tumor.COL1A1.Total = c(42, 85, 40, 71, 48, 8
    ), Tumor.DDR1.Total = c(2086, 1788, 1755, 1733, 1874, 1744
    ), Tumor.PanCK.Total = c(1393, 1765, 1054, 1490, 1393, 789
    ), Tumor.PanCK..DDR1..Total = c(157.7995, 317.2483, 166.8384, 
    196.1875, 155.4539, 133.8864), Tumor.PanCK..DDR1..Total.1 = c(1393, 
    1751, 1054, 1487, 1393, 783), stroma_percentage = c(0.151937599435602, 
    0.221499294034946, 0.271900228846863, 0.299998160266393, 
    0.273408810404253, 0.287608906222719), cd8_density = c(7.99884176771203e-06, 
    0, 7.99884176771203e-06, 1.19982626515681e-05, 1.99971044192801e-05, 
    2.13447445183494e-05), cd8_density_tumor = c(4.75778135140021e-06, 
    0, 0, 0, 5.53157005318605e-06, 0), cd8_density_stroma = c(2.6322785793066e-05, 
    0, 2.94182972983707e-05, 3.99944541023645e-05, 5.85119532606517e-05, 
    7.4214476869574e-05), stroma_bins = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("0-10%", "10-20%", "20-30%", "30-40%", 
    "40-50%", "50-60%", "60-70%", "70-80%", "80-90%", "90-100%"
    ), class = "factor"), row_id = 1:6, stroma_cd8_frac = c(3.99942088385602e-06, 
    0, 7.99884176771203e-06, 1.19982626515681e-05, 1.59976835354241e-05, 
    2.13447445183494e-05), tumor_cd8_frac = c(3.99942088385602e-06, 
    0, 0, 0, 3.99942088385602e-06, 0)), row.names = c(4040L, 
4140L, 4047L, 4078L, 4058L, 4036L), class = "data.frame")

And here's one of the plots showing the clipping problem.


Are some of the values outside the range specified in ylim(-0.003540187, 0.005720250) +? My understanding is that specifying x/y ranges in scale_x/y_*(limits = ....) or in xlim/ylim will filter out data beyond those ranges, while specifying ranges in coord_* will control the viewing window without censoring data. I wonder if there might be a way to do this with coord_radial? https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/03/ggplot2-3-5-0-coord-radial/

Yup, there's a few instances with values outside of the y limits, but I want to keep y limits consistent between samples so they are directly comparable. Thanks for making me aware of coord_radial, I hadn't heard of it before. Will test it out and report back.
